# Automatic by convention mapping coupled with Owned entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

We are on ef core 3.1.6. We have two special interfaces for our Entities.

*ICreated* and *IUpdated*

From the DB context we automatically add the config for these using

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(ICreated).Assembly);

    builder
        .Model
        .GetEntityTypes()
        .Where(et => typeof(IUpdated).IsAssignableFrom(et.ClrType))
        .ForEach(et => builder.Entity(et.ClrType).Property(nameof(IUpdated.UpdatedUTC)).IsConcurrencyToken());

    builder
        .Model
        .GetEntityTypes()
        .Where(et => typeof(ICreated).IsAssignableFrom(et.ClrType))
        .ForEach(et =>
        {
            var entity = builder
                .Entity(et.ClrType);

            entity
                .Property(nameof(ICreated.CreatedUTC))
                .IsRequired();

            entity.Property(nameof(ICreated.CreatedBy))
                .IsRequired();
        })
}
```

This have worked very well up to this point. But now we wanted to add a `ICreated` entity as a owned entity doing

```
builder.OwnsOne(p => p.PayerInfo, b =>
{
    b.WithOwner().HasForeignKey(p => p.PaymentTransactionId);
    b.ToTable("PaymentTransactionPayerInfo", "dbo");
});
```

This works if we do not add the `ICreated` interface. If we add the interface to the entity it will crash on this line `builder.Entity(et.ClrType)` With the exception

> The type 'PaymentTransactionPayerInfo' cannot be configured as
> non-owned because an owned entity type with the same name already
> exists

So for these i instead need to use the `OwnedNavigationBuilder`somehow. Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since EF Core won't let you use `Entity` method for obtaining entity type builder to be used with fluent APIs, I see two options:

1. Don't use fluent API, perform the configuration directly with mutable metadata APIs, e.g.:

```cs
builder
    .Model
    .GetEntityTypes()
    .Where(et => typeof(IUpdated).IsAssignableFrom(et.ClrType))
    .ForEach(et =>
    { 
        et.FindProperty(nameof(IUpdated.UpdatedUTC))
            .IsConcurrencyToken = true;
    });

builder
    .Model
    .GetEntityTypes()
    .Where(et => typeof(ICreated).IsAssignableFrom(et.ClrType))
    .ForEach(et =>
    {
        et.FindProperty(nameof(ICreated.CreatedUTC))
            .IsNullable = false;

        et.FindProperty(nameof(ICreated.CreatedBy))
            .IsNullable = false;
    });
```

2. Take a small risk of using internal API (have lo idea why they make it internal w/o providing a public way of getting the desired builder).

Add

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;
```

which will give you access to `AsEntityType()` extension method, and returned type has property `Builder` returning the entity type builder needed for fluent calls:

```cs
builder
    .Model
    .GetEntityTypes()
    .Where(et => typeof(IUpdated).IsAssignableFrom(et.ClrType))
    .ForEach(et => et.AsEntityType().Builder // <--
        .Property(nameof(IUpdated.UpdatedUTC)).IsConcurrencyToken());

builder
    .Model
    .GetEntityTypes()
    .Where(et => typeof(ICreated).IsAssignableFrom(et.ClrType))
    .ForEach(et =>
    {
        var entity = et.AsEntityType().Builder; // <--

        entity
            .Property(nameof(ICreated.CreatedUTC))
            .IsRequired();

        entity.Property(nameof(ICreated.CreatedBy))
            .IsRequired();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! 1 feels safer since it does not rely on "internal"  code. Thanks!